# Extracting first elements from a list of tuples using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples of which I want to extract the first element of each tuple to another list.
I had a list of tuples called `lst` and tried to extract the elements to a list called `lst2` and what I got was:

```
>>> lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> lst2 = []
>>> [lst2[i] = lst[i][0] for i in range(len(lst))]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [lst2[i] = lst[i][0] for i in range(len(list))]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The desired output is `[1, 3, 5]`.

Can you help figure out what's wrong with this syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Using `lst` and `lst2` as the variable names as others have noted `list` is a bad choice.

You don't need the index.  Using the index is often considered bad form.

`lst2 = [ pair[0] for pair in lst]`

If you really, really need the index, for some math or something.

`lst2 = [ lst[i][0] for (i, pair) in enumerate(lst)]`

If you need to manipulate 2 dimensional matrices of numbers, you might want to learn about `numpy` and look at `numpy.matrix` and `numpy.array`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the list comprehension, only expression can come. `list2[i] = list[i][0]` is an assignment **statement**.

And, you don't need to use indexes to access items. Just iterate the list.

```
>>> lst = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
>>> lst2 = [x[0] for x in lst]
>>> lst2
[1, 3, 5]
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin type/function [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
About the list thing: I know, I use list as a variable name only on terminal (runtime).

Comment: @coding_brainfart, Even in interactive shell, I recommend not to use `list`. Once you use it, you can't do something like: `list('abc')`.

Comment: @coding_brainfart - Guido (creator of Python) recommends suffixing names that would otherwise shadow built-ins with an underscore. So you could use `list_` instead of `list`, for example. Most often where I see this come up is `id_` to avoid shadowing the built-in function `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a variable using the equals operator while looping through a list in one line. You could simply do it like this:

```
list = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
list2 = []
[list2.append(list[i]) for i in range(len(list))]
```

Comment: You _could_, but you _really_ shouldn't. :) 1) Others have already mentioned using `list` as a variable name, but I guess you're just copying that from the question. 2) Using `for i in range(len(some_list))` is rarely necessary, since we can iterate over sequence types directly. 3) `list.append()` returns `None`, so you're wastefully creating a list full of `None and then throwing it away.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with `zip()`:

```
>>> lst = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
>>> zip(*lst)
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
>>> zip(*lst)[0]
(1, 3, 5)
>>> list(zip(*lst)[0])
[1, 3, 5]
```

However, it is a little wasteful when you only need the one list.